# How to optimize loop in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am running this short loop with 20 iterations to read 20 netcdf files and do simple calculations.
However it is very slow. Is the time consuming because of the ncread operation?

Any suggestions to speed up the code?

```
for i=1:20
    disp(i);
    ts2= ncread(Files(i).name,'TS2');

    Temp_summer(:,46:90,i) = mean(ts2(:,46:90,151:240),3); % Northern Hemisphere summer JJA
    Temp_summer(:,1:45,i) = mean(ts2(:,1:45,[1:60 336:365]),3); % Southern Hemisphere summer DJF   
end
```

Comment: If you are a CPU reading files is very slow, very very slow.  If you are a human, perhaps not so much.  But you give us no idea how large the files are, nor how slow reading them is.  `5s` slow for 20 files or `5h` slow ?

Comment: You can concatenate multiple netCDF files together and just read in one file. See ncrcat/ncecat in NCO: http://nco.sourceforge.net/

Comment: NETCDF files are about 1.2 gb each, and it takes about 200 seconds for the complete operation (iterating 20 times)

Comment: From where I sit I can't see a real problem.  It's taking your system about 10s to read a (large ?) dataset out of a NetCDF file; depending on the layout of the file this might mean a little bit of hunting around the disk.  Then you do some computations on chunks of the variable. If you've got any other parts of your code to optimise then go optimise them.  If not, you might get better performance by using the other input arguments to `ncread` to slice the dataset on input.  I'd be a bit surprised if you did, but you might.